# построение Блок-схемы

Tags: c++, блок-схема

Здраствуйте. Не подскажите какое либо пособие которые наглядно показывает как строить блок схемы для кодов C++ (а то я в этом вообще воробушек).
Если не составит струда постройте Блок схему для кода ниже, у меня получается полный бред.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int x1, x2, x3;
    int y1, y2, y3;
    int F1, F2, F3;

    cout << "Введите координаты точек 1 : ";
    cin >> x1 >> y1;

    cout << "Введите координаты точек 2 : ";
    cin >> x2 >> y2;

    cout << "Введите координаты точек 3 : ";
    cin >> x3 >> y3;

    F1 = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1,2) + pow(y2 - y1,2));
    F2 = sqrt(pow(x3 - x1,2) + pow(y3 - y1,2));
    F3 = sqrt(pow(x3 - x2,2) + pow(y3 - y2,2));

    if ((F1 = F2) & (F2 = F3)) cout << "Треугольник равносторонний"; else cout << "Треугольник не равносторонний";

    return 0;
}
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

исходя из пособия найденного в интернете у меня получилось это.

Comment: Видимо это "...Если не составит струда постройте Блок схему для кода ниже..." главное в Вашем вопросе. "...у меня получается полный бред..." - приложите его. Здесь принято помогать, а не делать чужую работу. Прежде, чем задавать вопрос, есть смысл почитать правила форума.

Comment: Неплохо получилось, однако не соблюдены размеры блоков, и обычно их располагают друг под другом (кроме условий и расширений)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// НАЧАЛО
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Предопределенный процесс
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int x1, x2, x3;
    int y1, y2, y3;
    int F1, F2, F3;

    //Данные (вывод)
    cout << "Введите координаты точек 1 : ";
    //Данные (ввод)
    cin >> x1 >> y1;

    //Данные (вывод)
    cout << "Введите координаты точек 2 : ";
    //Данные (ввод)
    cin >> x2 >> y2;

    //Данные (вывод)
    cout << "Введите координаты точек 3 : ";
    //Данные (ввод)
    cin >> x3 >> y3;

    //Действие
    F1 = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1,2) + pow(y2 - y1,2));
    //Действие
    F2 = sqrt(pow(x3 - x1,2) + pow(y3 - y1,2));
    //Действие
    F3 = sqrt(pow(x3 - x2,2) + pow(y3 - y2,2));

    //Условие
    if ((F1 = F2) & (F2 = F3)) 
        //Условие верно
        //Данные (вывод)
        cout << "Треугольник равносторонний"; 
    else 
        //Условие не верно
        //Данные (вывод)
        cout << "Треугольник не равносторонний";

    return 0;
    //Конец
}
```

[руководство по блоксхемам (что нужно рисовать)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)